# Show/Hide JQuery Slider Navigation Based On First & Last Slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am seeking help in showing and hiding the directional nav arrows on a self-made JQuery Slider.  The slider shows 2-3 images at a time depending on the viewport.  I want to be able to hide the next(right) arrow when the last slide has appeared in full view and hide the previous(left) arrow whenever the first slide is back to the first item in view.

Trying to find a way to know the positions of the first and last slide because the number of list elements will change and not be a set number.

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.control-right', function() {
  var itemWidth = $(this).parent().children('.module-slider').children('.slider-list').children('.slider-item').outerWidth() + 20;
  var leftIndent = parseInt($(this).parent().children('.module-slider').children('.slider-list').css('left')) - itemWidth;
  $(this).parent().children('.module-slider').children('.slider-list').animate({left: leftIndent}, 400);
});
$(document).on( 'click', '.control-left', function() {
  var itemWidth = $(this).parent().children('.module-slider').children('.slider-list').children('.slider-item').outerWidth() + 20;
  var leftIndent = parseInt($(this).parent().children('.module-slider').children('.slider-list').css('left')) + itemWidth;
  $(this).parent().children('.module-slider').children('.slider-list').animate({left: leftIndent}, 400);
});
```

The markup template is as follows

```
<div class="module">
  <div class="slider-control control-left"></div>
  <div class="slider-control control-right"></div>
  <div class="module-slider">
    <ul class="slider-list">
     <li class="slider-item"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of doing this. Because I do not know your slider code I will suggest something.

If you want to detect the position of an element you can use JQuery's [position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/) method

That way you can detect the position of an element and have something happen. But besides that what I would do if I made a slider would be to give the current slider a class like `".active"` and then in my javascript I would use conditionals to check for the element with the class of `".active"` meaning it is shown.

Something like this:

```
if( $(".element").hasClass("active") ){
     //do something
}
```

Again those are only suggestions, you can go about in whatever way suits your needs.